# how to add documents to bottom of the document column in Cloud Firestore through the Firebase console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

I'm adding data to cloud Firestore through the Firebase Console. I've added a collection and the corresponding documents and fields. When I click on  " ADD DOCUMENT", the new document appears randomly (as far as I can make out) on the document column. I want the newly generated document to appear at the bottom of the document column. The order matters when viewing the data on the app. The data is used in a recycler view.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Firestore does not order documents in the same way as the RTDB.  Auto IDs are not time related.  You will need to add a timestamp field and order your data by this field.

You can read about this [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document).

> Important: Unlike "push IDs" in the Firebase Realtime Database, Cloud
>   Firestore auto-generated IDs do not provide any automatic ordering. If
>   you want to be able to order your documents by creation date, you
>   should store a timestamp as a field in the documents.

Answer (score 0):

I used Firestore's "set" method instead of "add" and used a numerical date string; it is automatically adding and listing them in numerical order.

```
// Swift

let dataToSave: [String: Any] = ["example": "example"]
collectionRef.document(dateString).setData(dataToSave) { (error) in
}
```

If you use the "add" method, the key will be automatically generated with a random alphanumeric string.

The collection orders everthing alphanumerically, so setting your documents using keys of numbers or letters, exclusively, will allow for an ordered list.